# Leaflet Panning clears all markers

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using leaflet + the leaflet directive and I noticed last night that if I pan too far to the left or right it creates a new instance of the map which doesn't contain my geojson markers.

Is this a known issue or did I miss configure my code? (Couldn't find any issues online)

This one is sort of hard to explain so I made an album:

[http://imgur.com/a/T6Kfc](https://imgur.com/a/T6Kfc)

Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix it?

Also noteworthy here is that if I pan further to the left, and enter "Instance 3, 4 or 5" (etc...) I won't be able to see my markers until I pan back to "Instance 1".

Here's my relevant HTML & Controller code:

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="GeoJSONCenterController">

  <div class="container-fluid" id="map-canvas">
        <leaflet markers="markers" center="mapCenter" defaults="defaults"  geojson="geojson"></leaflet>
  </div>

</div>
```

Controller code:

```
app.controller("GeoJSONCenterController", [ '$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'leafletData', 'iconService', function($scope, $http, $filter, leafletData, iconService ) {

$scope.mapCenter = { 
    lat: 41.152194, 
    lng: 6.855469, 
    zoom: 3,
};

$scope.defaults = {
    attribution: "",
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 18
};

$scope.icons = iconService.local_icons;


// Get the geojson data from the USGS
$http.get("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson").success(function(data, status) {
    addGeoJsonLayerWithClustering(data);
});

 function addGeoJsonLayerWithClustering(data) {
     var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

     var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
         pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
             marker = new L.marker(latlng, {icon: L.icon($scope.icons.quake_icon)});
             return marker;
         },
         onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var date = $filter('date')(feature.properties.time, "short");
              var popupContent = "<p><span class=" + "event-type" + ">" + feature.properties.type + ":</span> " + "<a href=" + feature.properties.url + " target=" + "_blank" + ">" + feature.properties.title + "</a>" + "<br><span class=" + "event-time" + "> Time: </span>" + date + "</span> " + "</p>";
              layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
          }
      });
      markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
      leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
        map.addLayer(markers);
        //map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
      });
  }   

} ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `worldCopyJump` is set to `false`. Setting it to `true` should move your markers when you pan the map.

see: https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/doc/defaults-attribute.md and